# Why my svg animation is not working on safari displays?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a checkmark animation that works perfectly on chrome browers. However, when it comes to safari, the svg is not displaying at all.

```js
$('#checkmark-svg').on('click', function(){
  svg = $(this);
  svg.removeClass('run-animation').width();
  svg.addClass('run-animation');
  return false;
})
```

```css
.cls-1{
  fill:none;
  stroke:#231f20;
  stroke-miterlimit:10;
  stroke-width:5px;
}

.svg-check {
  position: inherit;
}

svg {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  
  .cls-1 {
    stroke: #2d77e3;
  }
}

.circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 700;
  stroke-dashoffset: 700;
}

.checkmark {
  stroke-dasharray: 150;
  stroke-dashoffset: 150;
}

.run-animation {  
  .circle {
    animation: 2.5s circleDraw forwards;
  }

  .checkmark {
    animation: 0.75s checkmarkDraw forwards;
    animation-delay: 1s;
  }
}

@keyframes circleDraw {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 700;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes checkmarkDraw {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 150;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

        <svg id="checkmark-svg" class="run-animation svg-check" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 193.3 193.3">
            <circle class="cls-1 circle" cx="96.65" cy="96.65" r="94.15"/>
            <polyline class="cls-1 checkmark" points="46.9 101.4 76.9 131.4 146.4 61.9"/>
        </svg>
```

The JS code is simply a refresh of the animation on click and might be omitted. Also, there is no background css class which might influence its behavior.

Comment: keyframe name is supposed to last in animation shorthand, maybe that's it? (Don't have my mac with me). aka animation: 0.75s forwards checkmarkDraw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the very recent [CSS nesting](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-nesting-1/) feature, which is [still not widely supported](https://caniuse.com/css-nesting) (only Chromium based browsers and the latest Safari Technology Preview, as of today).

By unnesting all your CSS rules, your code would work in all browsers, including Safari and Firefox:

```js
$('#checkmark-svg').on('click', function() {
  svg = $(this);
  svg.removeClass('run-animation').width();
  svg.addClass('run-animation');
  return false;
})
```

```css
.cls-1 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #231f20;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}

.svg-check {
  position: inherit;
}

svg {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
}
svg .cls-1 {
  stroke: #2d77e3;
}

.circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 700;
  stroke-dashoffset: 700;
}

.checkmark {
  stroke-dasharray: 150;
  stroke-dashoffset: 150;
}

.run-animation .circle {
  animation: 2.5s circleDraw forwards;
}
.run-animation .checkmark {
  animation: 0.75s checkmarkDraw forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes circleDraw {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 700;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes checkmarkDraw {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 150;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<svg id="checkmark-svg" class="run-animation svg-check" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 193.3 193.3">
    <circle class="cls-1 circle" cx="96.65" cy="96.65" r="94.15"/>
    <polyline class="cls-1 checkmark" points="46.9 101.4 76.9 131.4 146.4 61.9"/>
</svg>
```

Note that you can feature detect CSS nesting with an `@supports` rule:

```css
.elem::after {
  content: "Your browser does not support CSS nesting";
  color: red;
}
@supports (selector(&)) {
  .elem::after {
    content: "Your browser supports CSS nesting";
    color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class=elem></span>
```

But that would mean you'd have to go into the trouble of unnesting for the ones that don't support it anyway, so I'm not convinced of how useful that'd be for you.

Answer (score -2):

```
please use webkit for animation in css


.run-animation {  
  .circle {
    -webkit-animation: 2.5s circleDraw forwards;
            animation: 2.5s circleDraw forwards;
  }

  .checkmark {
    -webkit-animation: 0.75s checkmarkDraw forwards;
            animation: 0.75s checkmarkDraw forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
            animation-delay: 1s;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes circleDraw {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 700;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes circleDraw {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 700;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes checkmarkDraw {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 150;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes checkmarkDraw {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 150;
  }
  to {`enter code here`
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's not working + it broke my animation on chrome.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).